# Array with 2 centred, math-mode columns of width `\textwidth/2`

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, arrays, width

I'd like to have an array with 2 columns, each of which is centred, has width `\textwidth/2`, and is in math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{array}{cc}
c_1 & c_2
\end{array}\]
\end{article}
```

produces an array with 2 centred columns in math mode, but they fit to their contents.  My naïve and clumsy attempt

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{array}{cc}
\hfill c_1\hfill & \hfill c_2\hfill
\end{array}\]
\end{article}
```

doesn't seem to have any effect on the column width, for reasons that I'm sure a TeXpert can easily explain, but that I can't.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{array}{p{\textwidth/2}p{\textwidth/2}
c_1 & c_2
\end{array}\]
\end{document}
\end{article}
```

gives

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.5 c_
      1 & c_2
```

—the contents are not in math mode (and of course would not be centred if typeset).  The documentation of [array](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) says of `m{width}` :

> Defines a column of width `width`. Every entry will be centered in proportion to the rest of the line. It is somewhat like `\parbox{width}`.

So it seems unlikely to put the contents in math mode, but it seems that it should at least centre.  For me, it doesn't:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,calc}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{array}{m{\textwidth/2}m{\textwidth/2}
c1 & c2
\end{array}\]
\end{document}
\end{article}
```

typesets just fine, but the contents are neither centred nor in math mode—indistinguishable to me from `p{}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array` and the `w` column type.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

% show the center of the page
\noindent\hspace*{\fill}$|$\hspace*{\fill}

\[
\begin{array}{@{}w{c}{0.5\displaywidth}@{}w{c}{0.5\displaywidth}@{}}
c_1 & c_2
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Since we're in a math display, `\displaywidth` is the appropriate dimension.

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  Why doesn't `m` work?  Am I misreading the documentation?

Comment: @LSpice `m` makes text, not math; and `m` stands for “vertical centering”, not horizontal. The `w` column type produces text in `tabular` and math in `array`.

Comment: [Thank you](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/665058/array-with-2-centred-math-mode-columns-of-width-textwidth-2/665059#comment1653724_665059).  I had understood about the text, but not about the centring.